# Phpmyadmin database not accepting records

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wampserver

Can anyone help? So I am doing a php exercise with the wamp server. My form only accepts the record when I only have 3 columns but when I add on more columns the record is not being added.

Code below

html Form

```
<body>

  <form action = "Form.php" method = "post">

        <label> Title: </label> <input type = "text" name = "title"/>

        <label> First Name: </label> <input type = "text" name = "fname"/>

        <label> Last Name: </label> <input type = "text" name = "lname"/>

        <label> EmailAddress: </label> <input type = "text" name = "address"/>

        <label> Hobby: </label> <input type = "text" name = "hobby"/>

        <label> Sex: </label> <input type = "text" name = "gender"/>

        <label> UserName: </label> <input type = "text" name = "uname"/>



        <input type = "submit" name = "submitbtn" value = "Submit"/>


    </form> 




</body>
```

---

Php page

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitbtn'])){

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $hobby = $_POST['hobby'];
    $sex = $_POST['gender'];
    $uname = $_POST['uname'];

    $connect_db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Humans");

    if(!$connect_db){
        echo "Connection failed";
    } else 
         echo "Connection successful";

    if(!mysqli_select_db($connect_db, 'Humans')){
        echo "Database not selected";
    } else
        echo "Database selected";


    $sql = "INSERT INTO People(Title, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, Hobby, Sex, UserName)VALUES('$title','$fname','$lname','$address','$hobby','$sex','$uname')";
    if(mysqli_query($connect_db, $sql)){
        echo "Record was added";
    }else
       echo "Record was not added";
 }
 ?>
```

---

Output:

```
Connection successful
 Database selected 
Record was not added
```

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` **is not a database** its a tool written in PHP that allows you to maintain a **MYSQL** database

Comment: print query and run it in PhpMyadmin to see error, like echo $sql;die; copy and run this query in myadmin.

Comment: Simple code indentation make your code easier to read and more importantly **easier to debug**

Comment: echo "Record was not added - " . mysqli_error($conn);

Comment: password-less root, sql-injection issues, bad code indentation, et cetera.... you might want to spend more time learning how PHP and MySQL work before building out a database

Answer (score 0):

The PHP MySQL database extensions provide useful messages and codes when things go wrong, it would be a good idea to learn to use them.

So if you add `mysqli_error($connect_db)` to your message, you will find out what actually went wrong in your query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO People(Title, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress,
                           Hobby, Sex, UserName)
        VALUES('$title','$fname','$lname','$address',
               '$hobby','$sex','$uname')";

if(mysqli_query($connect_db, $sql)){
    echo "Record was added";
}else
   // add the error message so you see something useful
   echo "Record was not added " . mysqli_error($connect_db);
}
```

Now with luck, you can solve your own problems, but if not post the error message in your question and I can expand on this answer

Comment: thnks i found the problem